# CSS not working on safari , works fine on Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, safari

In CSS, while using `position:fixed`, I am getting different results when I try to open the same page on safari and Chrome. I have attached the screen-shots and the css code snippet.

```
.block--active {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 1%;
  bottom:2%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

It seems like using 'postion: fixed' is causing some issue and it makes the element generate on a different viewport, in my case the entire screen. What should have happened ( like in chrome ) is the element should in the parent 's viewport. So the width and height set to 100% should open the model only in parents viewport and not the entire scree.

Screenshots:

[Chrome ScreenShot :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62uoa.jpg)

[Safari Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4YHC.jpg)

````
.block-wrap {
  width: 900px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: auto;
}

.block-col {
  display: box;
  -webkit-display: box;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 12px;
  width: 128px;
}

.block {
  height: 128px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: auto 0;
  position: relative;
  will-change: transform;
}
.block:not(.block--active) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.block:not(.block--active):hover, .block:not(.block--active).fake-hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-12px);
          transform: translateY(-12px);
}
.block:not(.block--active):hover:after, .block:not(.block--active).fake-hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateY(12px);
          transform: scale(1.1) translateY(12px);
}

.block:not(.block--active):active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) translateY(-12px);
          transform: scale(0.9) translateY(-12px);
}
.block--active {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 1%;
  bottom:2%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
}
.block--active .clogo{
  width: 150px !important;
  height:150px !important;
}

.block--active .ctext{
  color: rgb(126, 122, 122) !important;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 25px;
}
.block--transition {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.185s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.185s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1);
  transition: transform 0.185s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1);
  transition: transform 0.185s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1), -webkit-transform 0.185s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1);
}

.block-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 24px;
}
.block--active .block-content {
  display: block;
}

.block-content__header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 24px;
  margin: -24px -24px 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgba(14, 13, 13, 0.85);

}

.block-content__header__text {
  will-change: transform;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: rgb(126, 122, 122);
}
.block--active .block-content__header__text {
  -webkit-animation: content-in 0.225s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1) forwards;
          animation: content-in 0.225s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1) forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .15s;
          animation-delay: .15s;
}

.block-content__body {
  will-change: transform;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.333;
  -webkit-animation: content-in 0.245s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1) forwards;
          animation: content-in 0.245s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1) forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .1s;
          animation-delay: .1s;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  color: rgba(14, 13, 13, 0.85);
 
}

.block-content__button {

}

@-webkit-keyframes content-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(128px);
            transform: translateY(128px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes content-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(128px);
            transform: translateY(128px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes button-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(64px);
            transform: translateY(64px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes button-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(64px);
            transform: translateY(64px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.t {
  background: #f5f4f0c9;
  color: #a2a79f96;
  border-top: 2px solid #68fe9a00;
}
.t:not(.block--active) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #03fd4200;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
      0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
      0px 1px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.t.block--active {
  background: #f6e975de;
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
}
.t .block-content__header {
  background: #35fd7100;
}
.t .block-content__button {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #03fd2d00;
  border-top: 2px solid #68feab00;
}```
````

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If our sample object worked properly in all browsers and came out shifted 5 pixels forward in the opera    .opera .object {margin-left: -5px; We would say}.

maybe this can help